# ValueError with multi-table inheritance in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, multi-table

I created two new classes which inherit model Entry:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = settings.LANGUAGES

    language = models.CharField(max_length=2, verbose_name=_('Comment language'), choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True, blank=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Comment(Entry):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Comment in English'))

class Discount(Entry):
    discount = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Comment in English'))
    coupon = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Coupon code if needed'))
```

After adding these new models to admin via admin.site.register I'm getting ValueError when trying to create a comment or a discount via admin. Adding entries works fine.

Error msg:

ValueError at /admin/reviews/discount/add/
Cannot assign "''": "Discount.discount" must be a "Discount" instance.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/reviews/discount/add/
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
Cannot assign "''": "Discount.discount" must be a "Discount" instance.
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in **set**, line 211
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.1

Comment: Can you paste/dpaste your view code that tries to save the model and the full traceback?

Comment: Traceback: http://dpaste.com/195193/
I'm getting this when going to "Add discount" in Django admin. Same error appears when try to create a new discount via shell (discount = Discount())

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this error appeared was because I used same column name that was already used with model name. Karen T. contributed the following answer in [Django mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/bdc3c63d43fe6707):

> The problem seems to be that you have
>   named a field in your Comment model 
>   with the same name, only lower case.
>   Comment inherits from Entry, using 
>   multi-table-inheritance. This adds a
>   OneToOneField in Comment back to
>   Entry,  which has a side-effect of
>   adding a 'comment' attribute to Entry.
>   This is  the attribute that lets you
>   access the Comment associated with the
>   Entry as  a result of the
>   OneToOneField in Comment, and by
>   default it is given the  name of the
>   related model, all-lowercase.
>
> The
>   problem then occurs when the Comment
>   model "inherits' all the 
>   fields/attributes of Entry: the
>   inherited 'comment' attribute from
>   Entry is  apparently over-riding the
>   specified comment field. That's
>   probably a bug,  but it appears to
>   have been there since 1.0. I have not
>   done any research to  see if it's been
>   reported.
>
> As a workaround you can
>   name your fields something other than
>   the model name  all lowercased, or you
>   can explicitly specify the
>   OneToOneField in the child  models,
>   specifying parent_link=True and
>   something other than the model name 
>   all lowercased for related_name.

Answer (score 0):

Hunch says you could do with declaring your Entry class as an abstract one unless you need an Entry as an actual object, too

```
...rest of Entry model here...
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) ## ONLY set date when created, not every save

class Meta:
   abstract = True

...methods for your model etc...
```

Comment: I decided to go with multi-table inheritance because I need to query mixed bag of objects in one list. Based on the documentation this should work: 

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/models/#id7